# what is the best way to update hundreds of existing records

Tags: soql, field-update, update

I need to update existing records. when i am trying to update single record in developer console(anonymous window) by passing ID in where clause. But, when i try to update multiple records i'am facing error. can any one please tell me is way of updating correct or not.

This is the query for update single record:

```
Accreditation__c accr = [SELECT Id, Account__c, Business_Plan__c 
                           FROM Accreditation__c WHERE id = 'a5PU0000000PCVX'];

accr.Business_Plan__c = [select Name from Business_Plan__c 
                          where Partner_Account__c = :accr.Account__c 
                            and Year__c = '2016'].id;

update accr;
```

This is the query for update multiple records:

```
    Accreditation__c[] accr = [SELECT Id,Business_Plan__c,Account__c FROM Accreditation__c WHERE isActive__c = true AND is_branch__c = true limit 2];

system.debug('accr size = '+accr.size());

if(!accr.isEmpty()){

for(Accreditation__c accrdt : accr)
   accrdt.Business_Plan__c = [select Name from Business_Plan__c where Year__c = '2016' AND Partner_Account__c = :accrdt.Account__c];

 update accr;
 }
```

The error is while updating multiple records:

> Illegal assignment from List to Id

Can anybody please suggest me to avoid this error or what is fastest way to update existing records.

Answer (score 3):

The error message means your query is not returning any results. I see that you're trying to query accounts that are from the same list your writing to, not the list you originally queried (accr.Account__c vs accrdt.Account__c). I suggest you rewrite it to look more like the following, esp since you're trying to return multiple records.

```
Accreditation__c[] accr = [SELECT Id,Business_Plan__c,Account__c FROM Accreditation__c WHERE isActive__c = true AND is_branch__c = true];
system.debug('accr size = '+accr.size());
if(!accr.isEmpty()){
   for(Accreditation__c accrdt : accr)
   accrdt.Business_Plan__c = [select Name from Business_Plan__c where  Partner_Account__c.Year__c = '2016' AND Partner_Account__c.Year__c IN :accr.Account__c];

   update accr;
 }
```

What's not clear is whether you initial query isn't returning any results or whether your 2nd query isn't returning any results. The debug and if statement should tell you that.

I don't know if adding that `id`at the end of your 2nd query will work for the for loop or if it's even needed. That part isn't clear to me. It's my sense that it's not, thus the reason I've omitted it and rewritten your query using the different structure in addition to using the correct variable. You can of course try it both ways since I don't know your schema. Clearly though the variable name is an issue.

**Edit**

I was so focused on the one error that I overlooked another obvious one.

`accrdt.Business_Plan__c` has to be of object type `Business_Plan__c` to which you can equate the query since it's not a field at that point, but instead an object.

Your code should look like this:

```
Accreditation__c[] accr = [SELECT Id,Business_Plan__c,Account__c FROM Accreditation__c WHERE isActive__c = true AND is_branch__c = true];
system.debug('accr size = '+accr.size());

if(!accr.isEmpty()){
   for(Accreditation__c accrdt : accr)
   Business_Plan__c bpc = [select Name from Business_Plan__c where  Partner_Account__c.Year__c = '2016' AND Partner_Account__c.Year__c IN :accr.Account__c];

   update bpc;
 }
```

Comment: Add the '.id' to the end of the declaration. 

Business_Plan__c bpc = [select Id from Business_Plan__c where  Partner_Account__c.Year__c = '2016' AND Partner_Account__c.Year__c IN :accr.Account__c LIMIT 1].id;

Comment: I need to update Accreditation__c. The Name in second query data type is auto number and the accrdt.Business_Plan__c is look up. look up relationship with  Business_Plan__c object. Is it shouldn't be like this?

Comment: If it's a look-up, the Business_Plan__c records need to be updated first. Once that happens, you can update the links or "connect" them to your Accreditation__c object by getting the Ids of those records. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: I'm sorry to make you confuse. The Business_Plan__c records having proper data. we need to compare the Partner account__c with Accreditation record's  Account__c field for all records queried in First SOQL. If these two matches then the Business plan_c's Name value should populate in Accreditation record's Business Plan__c field value. I hope you understand.

Comment: If that's the case, you need more than just the two queries. You'll want to put the results into a map and compare the values. If there's a discrepancy, only then do you assign or update the value from the one map to the other.

Comment: I did same thing as cropedy mentioned as one more answer. But not working. Can we updated that lookup field through data loader. if yes, Can you please help me find a way to do. Because I'm not able to do export Business Plan records which matches with Accreditation's account records.

Comment: @cropredy approach is about what I had in mind. If all of these approaches aren't working, I suspect there's information you're not providing us with to help you properly. If you're updating the look-ups to new values, on what basis are you doing that? What fields in Business_Plan__c are used for the match to Accreditation__c? Does a Partner Acct get a new Business_Plan__c? Is that what's happening? Are there fields other than the year? Are you creating them or are you updating them?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you needing to limit your update call to 2 records and how do you know which 2 records the query will return?

Assuming you need to update more than 2 records and you were just using 2 as an example AND you don't have multiple Business Plan Records in 2016 with the Same Partner Account value, I would format your code like this:

```
List<Accreditation__c> accList = new List<Accretitation__c>();

for(Accreditation__c accrdt : [SELECT Id,Business_Plan__c,Account__c FROM Accreditation__c WHERE isActive__c = true AND is_branch__c = true){
    for(Business_Plan__c bp : [select Id, Partner_Account__c from Business_Plan__c where Year__c = '2016']){
        if(accrdt.Account__c == bp.Partner_Account__c){
            accrdt.Business_Plan__c = bp.id;
            acctList.add(accrdt);
        }
    }
 }
if(acctList.size() > 0){
update acctList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My first answer is to use Data Loader/Excel or its ilk; but if you want to go the execute anonymous route:

```
// select all Accreditations that need to be updated
Accreditation__c[] accrList = [SELECT Id,Business_Plan__c,Account__c 
                            FROM Accreditation__c 
                            WHERE isActive__c = true AND is_branch__c = true];

// Find the Business Plans for 2016 that match Accreditation accountIds
// by first collecting all the ujique accountIds into a set and ..
// then fetching all Business Plans that have those accountIds
set<ID> aIdSet = new set<ID>();
for (Accreditation__c accr: accrList)
    aIdSet.add(accr.account__c);
// Place the Business Plans into a map keyed by accountId
map<ID,Business_Plan__c> aIdToBpMap = new map<ID,Business_plan__c>();
for (Business_Plan__c bp : [[select Name, partner_account__c from Business_Plan__c 
                           where Year__c = '2016' AND 
                           Partner_Account__c IN :aIdSet])
    aIdToBPMap.put(bp.partner_account__c,bp);   


// finally, go back through the Accreditations and use our map to find the 
// business plan for the same accountId.
for(Accreditation__c accr : accrList)
   accr.Business_Plan__c = aIdToBpMap.containsKey(accr.account__c)
                 ? aIdToBpMap.get(accr.account__c).id  // the BP id
                 : null;


update accrList; // empty lists work fine here
```

Now, having said that, execute anonymous can run into issues with improperly implemented trigger recursion controls or DML limits because the entire set of `Accreditation__c` that qualify will get updated in one transaction; not broken into separate 200 record transactions such as done in Data Loader

To work around this, you can modify the first query to exclude any Accreditation__c that already have a business_plan__c set to non null and run the execute anonymous multiple times, using Limit 200

Comment: Neymar -- (1) - I added comments; (2) the `?` and `:` notation is called a ternary expression -- evaluate condition, if true, execute the `?` expression, else execute the `:` expression. See Apex Doc; (3) as for Future, you must have triggers on these objects that are doing things ; since I don't know your data, you might want to add debug statements into the above to understand better

Comment: So do you want me place this code trigger handler(trigger) or execute in anonymous.

Comment: try running the above code with a limit 1 on the first soql to see if issue is in execute anonymous or elsewhere in your triggers

Comment: No it is not working in anonymous. Let me try in trigger....